# AWS Lambda function sometimes shows {"message": "Internal server error"}

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

so I have a situation where I have a lambda function written. So everything is working perfectly fine. All of a sudden when I run my end to end test making multiple http requests to api gateway , which invokes my lambda, I end up with

```
{"message": "Internal server error"}
```

Now this happens for a few minutes (very random).
A few minutes later My lambda function starts to work when I invoke it using my browser (api-gateway). In cloudwatch logs I just get this log output below

```
END RequestId: a31629a2-81ae-46a2-8836-7fcd0f91edda
```

Not really a detailed explanation as to why its happening.
I know theres nothing wrong with my code possibly, since I do get successful responses.

Comment: " multiple http requests " - check lambda metrics. Maybe you get throtteled.

Comment: Did you get timed-out error in CloudWatch?

Comment: It probably means that the AWS Lambda function did not return the expected result (timeout?). Take a look at the Lambda function's logs in CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: If cloudwatch isn't showing the error from within your code, then it is most likely a timeout issue. Increase the timeout on the lambda and see if cloudwatch logs an error.

Comment: In 2024 still faced this issue, I'm doing it in Go, returning string map with key "statusCode" & nil err solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the scenario is the same; no logs are printing in AWS Lambda. Then it is most likely a timeout issue. Increase the timeout on the Lambda and see if CloudWatch logs an error.

After increasing the timeout, my issue got sorted.

[image]